# C # beginner. Compiler errors

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and visual studio 2005
I created a new Console Application project in VS2005 and added a Class1.cs file to the existing Program.cs file that was created by default.

The Class1.cs file has the following simple code:

```
public class Class1
{

    public Class1()
    { 
    }

    ~Class1()
    {
    }

    public void PrintMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHello\n");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

And program.cs file has the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintMessage();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

> The name 'PrintMessage' does not exist in the current context.

Any help?

Thanks, Viren

Comment: BTW; beware of C# destructors. They really shouldn't be there 99% of the time :) Before you think about stuff like this, you need to read up on Finalize() and Dispose()

Comment: While this site is for programming questions, I think that perhaps you should read a tutorial or book on object oriented development.

Comment: btw, in C# in 99% you do need to declare finalizer ~Class1()  directly - it has to be used in very special cases

Comment: @Meeh: This is what he has IS a finalizer, not a destructor (as destructor's don't exist in C#, at least not really). In fact, any time you implement IDisposable you MUST implement a corresponding finalizer that calls it (at least it's the expected practice).

Comment: Yes, I know. But looked like he had a C++ background, since he made it without knowing that he should instantiate a class, so "destructor" was the word that carried the meaning the best.

Comment: I think it would be more likely to say that he's looking at a book. I don't think someone with a C++ (and thus object-oriented) background is going to ask why he can't call an instance method of another class without an instance. My point is that Finalizers are common, meaning that to say that they aren't needed 99% of the time is misinformation. While an empty finalizer block (like he has) is a waste of cycles since the GC *has* to call it, they're certainly not anomalous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the class where the method is. You must do that with:

```
Class1.PrintMessages();
```

Since Class1 is not static, you also need an instance of that class. You could do that with:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
```

Finally, you have to call the method prefixed with the instance variable. Your code will look something like this:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.PrintMessages();
```

If you want, you can shorten this code with the sentence

```
new Class1().PrintMessages();
```

that do the same as before.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
Class1 myClass = new Class1();
myClass.PrintMessage();
```

Or, what might be better since this seems like a utility function. Change your method definition to:

```
public static void PrintMessage()
```

So you can call it directly.

```
Class1.PrintMessage();
```

Answer (score 3):

The name 'PrintMessage' does not exist in the current context.

It exists in *another* context - that of class Class1. Since it is a public function of that (public) class, you can use it, by creating an instance of Class1 (the PrintMessage function is not static, so you need an instance of Class1 to call it) and then invoking the PrintMessage function on it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 someClass1Object = new Class1();
        someClass1Object.PrintMessage(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, *4* people were faster :)

Comment: I was typing out an answer when I saw 4 new answers pop up too ;)

Comment: I didn't see them pop up, my computer has crashed and I'm using one from a friend who refuses to upgrade from IE6 :D

Answer (score 2):

PrintMessage is not a method of the class "Program", it's a method of Class1. Try

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.PrintMessage();
```

You probably also want to go through a tutorial or two :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Class1().PrintMessage();
    }
}
```

or make `PrintMessage()` to be `static` so you can use it next way:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void PrintMessage()
    {
        // ..
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1.PrintMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `PrintMessage()` inside of your `Main` function (which is a function on the `Program` class) means that the compiler is going to look for a function called `PrintMessage()` somewhere in the program class.

What you have is called an *instance function* on the `Class1` class. In order to call this type of function, you need an instance of `Class1` in your function. Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1 myClass = new Class1();

    myClass.PrintMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the method `static` is probably what you want, rather than the other suggestions here:

```
public static void PrintMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nHello\n");
    Console.Read();
}
```

`static` tells the compiler that this method doesn't depend on an *instance* of a class. If that doesn't mean anything to you, read up on the topic of classes in your favourite C# book.

Answer (score 0):

Your **PrintMessage()** method is a method of the **Class1** class.  You have to reference that class to get to the method.

```
 class Program 
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Class1 c = new Class1(); //Create an instance of your class
         c.PrintMessage(); //Call the PrintMessage method of class Class1
     } 
 }
```

**Note:** You may want to rename Class1 to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the Class1 class in order to call a method of the class.  Try:

```
Class1 myClass = new Class1();
myClass.PrintMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Print message is not a part of Main:
u have to tell it where it is:

```
Class1 messageClass = new Class1();
messageClass.PrintMessage();
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to reference the class that print message . . . AKA: Class1.PrintMessage()

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that doesn't work without making it `static` first.

Comment: You are correct.  That is what I get for being stuck in the world of VB.NET right now . . .